# Using google calendar when I am get refresh access token from refresh-token I am getting this error "Token has been expired or revoked."

Tags: google-calendar-api

For this error I am using revoke token api

HTTP POST: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke?token=1//0g1p1bNuUikGhCgYIARAAGBASNwF-L9IrkSRg0fOS1cTVj04Tw2o5j80_e7zOtEp7lHmI32cRgodpx9iJ5ZzF6CA8zRi75Coztbk

Getting error like:
{
"error": "invalid_token",
"error_description": "Token expired or revoked"
}
How can Revoke refresh token?
How many days after refresh token expire?
Can you please help me for revoke refresh token?

Comment: This link https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration will help you